# Deleting rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a query

```
DELETE 
FROM   [dbo].[AKA$Item Stock Changes Log] AS gone,SELECT t.[Item No_] , 
       t.[Last Date Modified] , 
       t.[Location Code] 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT [Item No_] , 
                     [Last Date Modified] , 
                     [Location Code] , 
                     [Activity] 
              FROM   [dbo].[AKA$Item Stock Changes Log]) AS t 
WHERE  t.[Last Date Modified]< 
       ( 
              SELECT Max(b.[Last Date Modified]) 
              FROM   ( 
                            SELECT [Item No_] , 
                                   [Last Date Modified] , 
                                   [Location Code] , 
                                   [Activity] 
                            FROM   [dbo].[AKA$Item Stock Changes Log]) AS b 
              WHERE  b.[Location Code]=t.[Location Code] 
              AND    b.[Item No_]=t.[Item No_]) as needed 
WHERE  gone.[Item No_]=needed.[Item No_] 
AND    gone.[Location Code]=needed.[Location Code] 
AND    gone.[Last Date Modified]=needed.[Last Date Modified]
```

Subquery called `needed` contains the rows i want to delete. But the query does not work and Im not sure how to handle this.

Here is some sample data.
The main goal for me would be a query that gets rows that have `[Item No_]` and `[Location Code]` equal and deletes all but the newest

```
Item No_             Last Date Modified      Location Code
-------------------- ----------------------- --------------------
0015672              2017-12-28 14:28:51.847 JV                  should stay
0015672              2017-12-28 14:28:51.847 KN                  should stay
0015672              2017-12-28 14:28:48.990 JV                  delete
0015672              2017-12-28 14:28:48.990 KN                  delete
0015672              2017-12-28 14:28:30.547 JV                  delete
0015672              2017-12-28 14:28:30.547 KN                  delete
0036539              2017-12-28 14:27:54.190 KN                  
0036539              2017-12-28 14:27:54.190 JV                  
0044623              2017-12-28 14:27:54.190 KN                  
0044623              2017-12-28 14:27:54.190 JV                  
0036539              2017-12-28 14:27:48.850 KN                  
0036539              2017-12-28 14:27:48.850 JV
```

Comment: "does not work"?   Do you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER()`. This will delete the records from the source table.

```
;with cte as (
select 
    *
    ,RN = row_number() over (partition by [Item No_], [Location Code] order by [Last Date Modified] desc)
from
    YourTable)

delete from cte where RN <> 1
```

Comment: Wow. This use of row_numbers was unknown for me. It is Excellent and fast. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem at all @HellOfACode